# Oauth2: Access Token & Refresh token, are both the same?

Tags: oauth-2.0, token

I have an Authorization server based in Oauth2. Together with the access token an refresh token is sent too.

I can get a resource with the access token and when it expires I request a new one with the refresh token.

However I can get a resource with the refresh token too... is it a typical behavior of Oauth2? I thought this refresh token was only for request new access tokens and not for get protected resources too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same question when i was use Oauth2 implementation in my project. Could you please see this presentation [Oauth2](http://www.slideshare.net/rohitsghatol/oauth-20-simplified)! which help a lot what is refresh token , access token when we use both what it does everything it covers and if its same or not also.

Comment: I don't understand you @sakthi. I try to know why the refresh token can get protected resources when the teory say that this refresh token is only for request new access token.